# What is the difference between habit, custom, practice and convention?

Tags: word-choice, word-difference

What are the differences between them? They all indicate doing something regularly throughout time and space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- **habit**
  The way an *individual* does things on a regular base. Example: *Smoking is a bad habit*.
- **custom**
   The long-established tradition of an entire **society**. Example: *Kissing a friend's cheek is a French custom, but not done in Saudi Arabia*.
- **practice**
  Similar to "habit", but normally positive, often with an undertone of professionality or praising an effort.
- **convention**
   Set of (unwritten or explicit) rules agreed upon within a group (applied to "people with common interests", not a "society"). Example: *Programmers use coding conventions to ensure easier readability of each other's code.*

(Please note: I'm dealing with the synonymous menaings only.)